# Magento 2. Order View Addresses not showing

Tags: magento2, sales-order, address

I have some wierd issue with Order View Addresses as can be seen in print-screen

What I've done: rm manually `pub/static/frontend` + `static content deploy`

Any tips? 
FWI: This happend after I upgraded 2.1.8 > 2.2.2

EDIT:
Nothing in logs. Nothing in web console

[image]

Comment: Any console errors?

Comment: There is nothing shown in console. Found some issues on github and started one myself. Is still not clear to me what is causing this.